# Pulse audio equaliser that has presets?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 17.04

I've used it before in 16.10 but I'm unable to find it for 17.04

I used these commands

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol && pavucontrol
```

Also tried to use PPA for `pulseaudio-equalizer`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

and all I got was this (for GUI)

[image: Screenshot]

But I want something with more control where I can increase bass and treble or audio frequencies in short

[image]

This is what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to find it

Comment: After adding a PPA you have to run `sudo apt update` and then install the package with `sudo apt install pulseaudio-equalizer`. Have you done it this way?

Comment: Yes! I know how ppa works (I'm not trying to be rude)

Comment: Oh, it's you, I haven't looked who asked the question, if I had looked I wouldn't have written my comment...

Comment: @mook765 I've updated an image that shows what i'm looking for. (17.04 has been a frustration so far)

Comment: Yes, it should look like this. How do you start `pulseaudio-equalizer`? There should be an entry in your start menu.

Comment: @mook765 i started it with the app icon named *pulse audio volume control* that's the only things appeared in gnome app drawer . which wasn't the case in 16.10 or 16.04 or 15.10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57890/discussion-between-mook765-and-sumeet-deshmukh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading and installing UbuntuGnome 17.04 I added the same PPA you used and installed `pulseaudio-equalizer` and `pulseaudio pavucontrol` and ran into the same problem, no icon was added to the dashboard and I couldn't start `pulseaudio-equalizer` in any way.

Checking all the files I found with a file-search for `pulseaudio` and intensive internet research led me to [this page in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Equalizer) where I found a solution:

> Edit the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` or `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` file with your
>   favorite editor and append the following lines:
>
> ```
> ### Load the integrated PulseAudio equalizer and D-Bus module
> load-module module-equalizer-sink
> load-module module-dbus-protocol
> ```

After doing that I rebooted and ran `qpaeq` in terminal. This opened the graphical interface, but playing around with the sliders had no effect.

> If qpaeq has no effect, install pavucontrol and change 
>   "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" to "FFT based equalizer on ..." 
>   while the media player is running. (in the Playback-tab)

That did the job. This setting seems to persist (at least as long `qpaeq` was running, even if I closed and reopened the media-player).

The interface looks a bit different from the image you posted and there are no built-in presets, but there is an option to save presets.

Comment: This worked, adding desktop entry for `qpaeq`

Comment: That's `qpaeq` that was in 16.04 and it had presets. They're somehow not there in 17.04.

Comment: `pulseaudio-equalizer` is in the official repository now, there is no need to add a PPA for it.