# pulseaudio-equalizer not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Yesterday I upgraded for Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 and pulseaudio-equalizer is no longer working. This is similar to the question asked here:

[Pulse audio equaliser that has presets?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909879/pulse-audio-equaliser-that-has-presets)

The solution for that question, to use qpaeq, is not a good one for me because I use bluetooth speakers and qpaeq only seems to work on the internal speakers or the headphone jack (not bluetooth speakers)

I have completely removed and re-installed pulseaudio and pulseaudio-equalizer, but the equalizer isn't available in the launcher and I get "command not found" when I try to run it from the terminal.

I'm looking for a solution to use an equalizer with my bluetooth speakers. Either by getting pulseaudio-equalizer to work as it did in 16.10 or to get qpaeq to work with the bluetooth speakers.

I'm a bit of a novice with Ubuntu/Linux so any input is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: same boat here -- and I'm pretty handy with apt-get

Comment: Tried in Ubuntu 17.04. Works like charm!

Answer (score 2):

If this helps anyone,the FFT based equalizer has to be selected as the output device in the sound app in linux cinnamon. I could not understand why it stopped working. Slider controls had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

*The OP posted the following as an edit to their question. I am reproducing it as an answer.*

---

I was able to fix my issue by force installing the version of pulseaudio-equalizer in the webupd8 ppa. Here's what I did:

1 - Install webupd8 ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
```

2 - Using Synaptic Package Manager I searched for and selected "pulseaudio-equalizer". From the "Package" menu I chose "Force Version" then I selected 2.7.0.2-5~webupd8~xenial0 . This also installs a bunch of dependencies.

Now it works just as before. I guess this is technically a "downgrade" but I'll gladly take a functional downgrade over a non-functioning upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Could give a try to [following solution](https://www.dotpointer.ga/?section=notes&view=note&id_notes=71)