# Qpaeq not working on 17.10

Tags: sound, lubuntu, python, pulseaudio, dbus

I am running Lubuntu 17.10. Loading qpaeg with:

```
pactl unload-module module-equalizer-sink
pactl unload-module module-dbus-protocol
pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink
pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
qpaeq
```

I get no module load errors and the qpaeq pops up correctly. When I change any of the sound levels it has no effect on sound output, and on the console above I get,

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/usr/bin/qpaeq", line 450, in write_coefficient
    self.filter_state.seed()
  File "/usr/bin/qpaeq", line 511, in seed
    self.sink.SeedFilter(self.channel,self.filter_frequencies,self.coefficients,self.preamp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: xs must be monotonic and 0<=x<=16384
```

Does anyone have any helpful suggestions? I have tried the many suggestions I have seen on the web, but nothing works.

Is there a way to revert to an older version that works? I tried
[pulseaudio-equalizer not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910479/pulseaudio-equalizer-not-working#927086)
but after following the procedure I was not offered the old version by synaptic.

Comment: My thanks to Vlad for tidying this up. I made the mistake of not checking that cut&paste had come out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this. Because it happened inadvertently the details are incomplete, but there it is.

I had upgraded to 18.04 as per the auto recommend. The problem persisted with the same behaviour, but a slightly different error message.

I installed pulseeffects. Following another Ubuntu post,
[pulse audio equaliser not working in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031916/pulse-audio-equaliser-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04)

So as root:

> wget [https://launchpad.net/~yunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/+files/pulseeffects_1.313entornosgnulinuxenial-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/+files/pulseeffects_1.313entornosgnulinuxenial-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
>
> dpkg -i pulseeffects_1.313entornosgnulinuxenial-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

The dpkg install failed lacking python-cairo, so

> apt install python-cairo

That failed also, but suggested:

> apt --fix-broken install

which installed python-cairo and a various other stuff (that is where I lack detail here - I didn't save the list).

Then I re-tried the dpkg install and it worked.

I now had pulseeffects installed and working.

I tried pulseaudio-equalizer again out of interest and it now worked. I guess that python-cairo or the stuff that got installed with it fixed the problem.

BTW I would recommend pulseeffects. The up/down keys can be used to make precise 1Db changes in each frequency range bar, and the 'tone' facility has enabled calibrating a 'flat' response from my amp & speakers. It revealed a massive hole in the response at 250cps. It all sounds so much better now.